# Read json from string in java

Tags: java, json

How to read the data from the below JSON if the JSON data is in the string

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "values": [
        {
            "valu": "23",
            "valu1": "24",
            "valu2": "25"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered so often that you actively need to turn the other way when SO proposes you the "related" questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and one of `Gson#fromJson` methods

[fromJson(String, Class)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

```
YourType o = new Gson().fromJson("your json string", YourType.class);
```

[fromJson(Reader, Class)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Class%29)

```
YourType o = new Gson().fromJson(new StringReader("your json string"), 
    YourType.class);
```

Simple example:

Define the class(s) you want to map the json data to:

```
static class Hobby {
    Hobby(String n) { name = n; }
    String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hobby [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

static class Person {
    String firstName, lastName;
    int age;
    List<Hobby> hobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", age=" + age + ", hobbies=" + hobbies + "]";
    } 
}
```

Now Test with the following Json String

```
@Test
public void fromJson() {
    Person o = new Gson().fromJson(
            "{\r\n" + 
            "    \"firstName\":\"John\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"lastName\":\"Doe\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"age\":24,\r\n" + 
            "    \"hobbies\":[\r\n" + 
            "        {\r\n" + 
            "            \"name\":\"Programming\"\r\n" + 
            "        },\r\n" + 
            "        {\r\n" + 
            "            \"name\":\"Sports\"\r\n" + 
            "        }\r\n" + 
            "   ]\r\n" + 
            "}",
            Person.class);
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

This prints:

```
Person [firstName=John, lastName=Doe, age=24, hobbies=[Hobby [name=Programming], Hobby [name=Sports]]]
```

see the javadoc of the class [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) for other alternatives. Also have a look at their [user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: @amrutha it is the tpye you want to convert the json String to, a class that you have to create. Please see the user guide I have linked to.

Comment: @amrutha, I have added a small example, see my edit.

Comment: Can any one help me to consume and produce a json using restful webservice

Answer (score 1):

You will need some library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to do the parsing for your. See also [Jackson tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). I think it would be easiest for you to start with [tree model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel).

Comment: Can any one help me to consume and produce a json using restful webservice

Comment: @amrutha: Find a [Spring+JSON tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)?

Comment: Without Spring i need an example to consume and produce JSON

Answer (score 1):

```
  try {

             String data = null;
             String url = "localhost:8080/test/rest/Action/xyz";
             String[] dataArray = null;
             DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpUriRequest getRequest = new HttpGet(getUrl);
             getRequest.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
             getRequest.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("key",
                "pwd"), "UTF-8", false));
             getRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

             HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
             System.out.println("Response Code : " +  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
             data = rd.readLine();

            }

        } catch () {
       }

try {

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        dataArray = data.split(",");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(data);

    try {
        JSONArray mjSONArray = mJSONObject.getJSONArray("values");
        for (int i = 0; i < mjSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj;
            obj = mjSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            valu = obj.getString("valu");
            valu1= obj.getString("valu1");
            valu2= obj.getString("valu2");
            system.out.println(valu);               
            system.out.println(valu1);               
            system.out.println(valu2);
        }
```

Using this you can get all the jsonarray data in variables.

Comment: if the above json is from url can i read it without saving it to string

Comment: public class olaptemplate {
public static void main(String[] args)    {
try {
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/test/rest/Action/xyz");
httpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())));
String output;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {sb.append(output
);System.out.println("Data,." + output);}
conn.disconnect(); } catch (){ }}}

Comment: here my url has json data

Comment: i am able to print it but how to save individual data into a variable and use it further

Comment: what do u want in variable? json array or single json value?

Comment: json array and each value in that array

Comment: getting the below exceptionA JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: make sure you have data in jsonobject?

Answer (score 0):

There are many JSON parsers.
I found [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) easy to implement.
A set of [decoding-examples](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) show how to create an JSON-Object out of String

Here is a code-snippet to read a JSON object from String. (Took this snippet directly from the decoding-examples page link above.)

```
  System.out.println("=======decode=======");

  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
  Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
  System.out.println("======the 2nd element of array======");
  System.out.println(array.get(1));
  System.out.println();

  JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
  System.out.println("======field \"1\"==========");
  System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));    


  s="{}";
  obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,]";
  obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,,2]";
  obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);
```

JSONObject is a java.util.Map and JSONArray is a java.util.List, so you can access them with standard operations of Map or List